# How to render correctly <ion-tabs> element?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I input route `/places/tabs/discover`.

Here are `app-routing.module.ts` and `app.component.html`

```
//app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'places', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then( m => m.AuthPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'places',
    loadChildren: () => import('./places/places.module').then( m => m.PlacesPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'bookings',
    loadChildren: () => import('./bookings/bookings.module').then(m => m.BookingsPageModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

<!--app.component.html-->
<ion-app>
    <ion-menu side="start">
    //...
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

As you see `PlacesPageModule` is loaded first.
Now please see `places-routing.module.ts`

```
//...
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/places/tabs/discover',
    pathMatch: 'full' 
  },
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: PlacesPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'discover',
        loadChildren: () => import('./discover/discover.module').then( m => m.DiscoverPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'offers',
        loadChildren: () => import('../offers/offers.module').then( m => m.OffersPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/places/tabs/discover',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PlacesPageRoutingModule {}
```

Hence, component `PlacesPage` is loaded into `ion-router-outlet` located in `app.component.html`.
Next, `PlacesPage` contains `<ion-tabs>` element inside its template.
Then `DiscoverPage` from `DiscoverPageModule` is loaded into the `router-outlet` represented by `ion-tabs` element. Here is what I see as a result.

[image: Layering of components]

How to remove the layering so that I see only toolbar of `DiscoverPage`, but also Tab buttons of `PlacePage`?

Answer (score 0):

File `places.page.html` contained `<ion-header>` element. I removed it.